# How to split a dynamic list into batches so that it doesn't exceed Apex CPU Limit?

Tags: apex, cpulimit, aggregateresult

I have a apex class which uses a many aggregate queries to form a list<Survey__c>.

1. Apex CPU limit is exceeded when I try to insert this list. I have already divided the list into two parts, but the CPU time is still exceeded.
   [image]

I basically need to divide this into smaller chunks of data to insert (less than 200 or 150 records). Can anyone help me achieve this?

2. Also, what will happen if the list size is a prime number? (Eg: 5179 records) Will I still be able to divide it by any number?
3. Is there any other way to handle this error?

Thank you!

Comment: please don't paste screen shots of code; use the code formatting tool; see [ask]

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have misunderstood the term "batch" here. What you are doing is not batching, but rather simply invoking `insert` multiple times in a row, synchronously.

Fundamentally you need to avoid inserting all your records *in one session*; it isn't a matter of reducing the size of each `insert` DML call but rather of reducing the number of records inserted synchronously (i.e. in the same apex code execution).

You need to go learn about asynchronous apex (future methods would not be appropriate here since you cannot pass complex data to one, whilst Batchable or Queueable may or may not be, depending just what you are doing in the code we cannot see in your question). Start with this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex).